# I can only dig 25” deep for a vinyl fence post . Is that enough with concrete? The fence is 6”

Tags: fence

Can I get by with a 25” deep fence post for vinyl fence post ? It’s for a 6’ vinyl fence

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What kind of soil, wind, and environment are we talking here?

Comment: why can you only dig 25"

Comment: I live near Pittsburgh, Pa and that for me is not deep enough. The winter freeze lifts the posts a couple inches each year so I need to did my holes deeper.